# How To Create A Startup Script To Run Both Grunt Watch and XAMPP

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, scripts, xampp

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu and I'm a web developer.

I created this small script to run Grunt watch and XAMPP at the same time.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
cd /home/mohammed/Dropbox/htdocs/my-site
grunt watch
```

My script name is web-services.sh and currently it lives in my home directory.

I run this script each time I turn on my computer from the terminal.

I read many tutorials and tried many times to make this script run at startup but each time I try only the XAMPP run!

**Please explain your answer in step by step process, for example where should I put the script in `/etc/init.d` or in another location and the commands that I need to run to make it work and so on and so forth.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That could be that the `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start` is not put in the background, so your script wait for it to stop before continuing.

Did you try to launch it in the background ? You can do that by adding a `&` at the end of the line :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start &
cd /home/mohammed/Dropbox/htdocs/my-site
grunt watch
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I tested it and it didn't work.